# How to sort multiple columns in a multitable query?

Tags: sql, sorting, ms-access, multiple-columns, multi-table

I have a question about how to find salary discrimination based on the employee gender. I have MS Acess 2007 and must use SQL queries to figure it out

Keep in mind, this is after I joined 3 tables together into one multi-table query. Within this query, whenever I want to sort any column with, for example, an `ORDER BY Salary`, it gives me an error sign saying:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Salary'
WHERE JobClass.JobClassID = Employees.JobClassID 
AND Department.DepartmentID = Employees.DepartmentID'.
```

I want to try to sort more than one column within the query.

Here is the multitable query code in total:

```
SELECT JobClass.JobClassID, JobClassName, Department.DepartmentID, 
       DepartmentName, LastName, FirstName, Title, Sex, Years, Salary
FROM  JobClass, Employees, Department
ORDER BY 'Salary'
WHERE JobClass.JobClassID = Employees.JobClassID AND Department.DepartmentID = Employees.DepartmentID;
```

Comment: `order by` should be after `where` clause

Comment: and remove '  ' from the ORDER BY 'Salary'

Answer (score 1):

> Order by Clause should be come after the where clause

Try like this

```
SELECT JobClass.JobClassID, JobClassName, Department.DepartmentID, 
       DepartmentName, LastName, FirstName, Title, Sex, Years, Salary
FROM  JobClass, Employees, Department
WHERE JobClass.JobClassID = Employees.JobClassID AND Department.DepartmentID = Employees.DepartmentID
ORDER BY Salary
```

**SLECT SYNTAX**

```
SELECT [predicate] { * | table.* | [table.]field1 [AS alias1] [, [table.]field2 [AS alias2] [, …]]}     
FROM tableexpression [, …] [IN externaldatabase]     
[WHERE… ]    
[GROUP BY… ]     
[HAVING… ]     
[ORDER BY… ]     
[WITH OWNERACCESS OPTION]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless Access '07 completely disregards standard SQL ( and I don't think it does) your SQL Syntax is off.

Instead of putting the `ORDER BY` *before* the `WHERE` clause, it should go *after* the `WHERE`.

Comment: Umm, there is no `WHILE` clause in SQL.

Comment: oh, sorry, WHERE.  Duh.